# renewing provisioning profile and certificates

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 2 iOS certificates - one for development and one for distribution (App Store).  Both are expiring in 2 weeks. I am on Xcode 4.4.1.  I have 2 development provisioning profiles and 4 distribution provisioning profiles.

In Xcode, I see that all of the provisioning profiles tied to the distribution certificate are set to expire in 2 weeks.  I went into the Organizer->Provisioning Profiles and tried to Renew, but I received an error dialog indicating that "No value was provided for the parameter 'deviceids'".   When I look on the Apple Provisioning Portal for that profile, it shows that the certificate is expiring in 2 weeks and that there are no devices associated with it (which is the way I've been doing it all along).

So - I'm trying to renew these, and haven't done this before.  Has anyone seen a similar error in Xcode?  Do I need to renew my certificate first, and if so, how?  I don't see any "create new certifcate" button on the Provisioning Portal or in Xcode.

Comment: Have you updated your annual developer license?

Comment: Having the same problem over here. Tried to renew it from several different accounts but still get the same error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem after I recently renewed my certificate.

The following corrected the issues for my *Development Provisioning Profile*:

- Click *Refresh* in **Xcode Organizer**.
- Ensure the *Code Signing* build settings for your **Project** and **Target** are set to the proper *Provisioning Profile*. You should select *iPhone Developer* to avoid future issues.
- Optionally, remove expired profiles from **Device** tab in **Xcode Organizer**.

The following corrected the issues for my *Distribution Provisioning Profile*:

- Log in to your [iOS Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)
- Go to the *Distribution* tab under *Provisioning*
- Create a new distribution profile.
- After the profile is generated, click *Refresh* in **Xcode Organizer**

Answer (score 5):

OK - I think I've fixed this.  Here is what I did and it seems to work - when I upload the next release I'll know for sure.

- In X-Code, I deleted all of my provisioning profiles
- I then quit out of X-Code
- From the Development Portal, I revoked my developer and distribution certificates
- I created new keys using the Key Chain application
- Still in Key-Chain, I removed my old, soon to be expiring key/certificate
- Back on the Development Portal, I created new certificates
- Still on the Development Portal, I was able to edit all of my provisioning profiles and associate the correct new certificate to it
- I downloaded the new profiles
- I then followed this link's advice and worked around the apparent bug in X-Code to remove the old provisioning profiles from my project:  [Codesign error: Provisioning profile cannot be found after deleting expired profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof)
- Started X-Code back up and copied the provisioning profiles into Organizer
- Built for a device and tested OK.
- Built for IOS Device as though I'm preparing to upload to the AppStore and build was successful.  I haven't tried uploading to the store.

I actually did the steps twice, once for the development profiles and then once that worked/tested on my test devices, I modified the distribution profiles.

These set X-Code up w/ no warning and Organizer now shows all my valid provisioning profiles that won't expire for another year.  Hopefully, next year, if I don't forget these steps, I'll be able to do it a bit more quickly.

Comment: it's ridiculous that this is the only way to get this working. surely apple can't make things this convoluted for devs?

Comment: Good Lord God Almighty!!! I can't believe what's going on - I've spent all day trying to get my app to compile to my 3rd gen ipod touch running 4.3.3 - I've tried everything, so much so that I've forgotten what I've changed. Do I now have to try this as well? Will it work or be another waste of time?

Comment: As an update to my answer, it worked fine when I deployed to the AppStore.

Comment: Im not going to delete ALL my profiles... I have more than 40 apps with each 1 developer, 1 ad hoc and 1 distribution profile. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Mark i am in the same situation as you, well, similar. I have 13 devices all connected to a specific profile with an application deployed to all devices, testing profile. My profile has expired, i am simply trying to renew it, If i go through the whole process again of profile creation with new keys etc, and i then push the application on my server, will the others still be able to download it?

Answer (score 3):

An easier way of doing it is ...

My certificate had expired, so the renew button button in the Xcode Organizer did not work.

I did the following:

- logged into the iOS provisioning portal
- went to provisioning profiles > distribution
- clicked on each of the expired profiles and clicked edit
- the certificate radio button was unchecked because my certificate had expired, so I checked it and clicked generate
- you'll then be prompted to download the newly generated profile.... dont!
- wait about 5 minutes
- go into the Xcode Organizer > provisioning profiles and click refresh
- the profiles should then change from "expired" to "valid"