# What happens if my distribution certificate expires?

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store, code-signing, certificate-expiry

My certificate will expire in 4 days, and I've uploaded for submission new app version with the new certificate. 
What happens if the old certificate expires? Will users be available do download my app with old certificate, or will Apple remove my app until the new certificate is provided?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

**What happens if my certificate expires or has been revoked?**

**Apple Push Notification Service Certificate**

You can no longer send push notifications to your app.

**Pass Type ID Certificate (Passbook)**

If your certificate expires, passes that are already installed on users' devices will continue to function normally. However, you will no longer be able to sign new passes or send updates to existing passes. If your certificate has been revoked, your passes will no longer function properly.

**iOS Distribution Certificate (App Store)**

If your iOS Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the App Store.

**iOS Distribution Certificate (In-house, Internal Use Apps)**

Users will no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with this certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that is signed with a new certificate.

**Mac App Distribution Certificate and Mac Installer Distribution Certificate (Mac App Store)**

If your Mac Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the Mac App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the Mac App Store.

**Developer ID Application Certificate and Developer ID Installer Certificate (Mac Applications)**

If your certificate expires, users can still download, install, and run versions of your Mac applications that were signed with this certificate. However, you will need a new certificate to sign updates and new applications. If your certificate has been revoked, users will no longer be able to install applications that have been signed with this certificate.

Original Source [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/)

Comment: So, I'll have to make a new build for all the apps I had distributed in-house with the expired certificated?

Comment: Hi, so to renew a distribution certificate (mine is expiring in 10 days) i need to revoke it. But if i revoke and request for a new one, will i be able to send updates with this new distribution certificate(it is saying i wont be able to send updates)?

Comment: @anish you need to update your build too...as an app in App Store works with related bundle identifier.
But if you renew your membership plan then the app in App Store keep in working.

Comment: To clarify, **iOS Distribution Certificate (App Store)** and **iOS Distribution Certificate (In-house, Internal Use Apps)** is one and the same certificate, created when selecting the **Production -> App Store and Ad Hoc** option on *developer.apple.com*, correct? The difference is that the former is used on the App Store while the latter - with Ad Hoc distribution. So am I correct to understand that any Ad Hoc app will have to be re-distributed at least once a year to continue working due to certificate expiring?

Comment: @SaltyNuts the difference is that in adhoc certificate you can add devices for testing purpose while for Appstore the distribution certificate dont include any devices.

Comment: So hold on, you're saying that I won't be able to update my app??? Obviously I'd have to at some point (soon, actually.)

Comment: you need to renew the certificate:-- follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974900/renewing-provisioning-profile-and-certificates

Comment: @iphonemaclover I had installed an application from xCode with my **"Developer certificate"**. If this certificate get expired then does my installed app affect? I know that if I want to update the app I need to update the certificate as well, but if I don't want to update or reinstall, I just want to continue using the installed app then is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will happen if my VoIP service certificate is expired? Will i need to submit new app with new certificate or existing users can download and use the app from appstore?

Comment: And what happens when FairPlay Streaming certificate expires?

Comment: @rdurand, if distribution certificate expires and the app is on live on the app store, will receive a push notification or not? Please answer?

Comment: you need to update push certificate as well

Answer (score 20):

When distribution certificate expires, you can't submit new apps to AppStore. On the other hand the old live apps will work fine, ie: Nothing will happen to your live app in AppStore.

Consider check these Apple's [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2333107?start=0&tstart=0) and [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH20-SW2).

Comment: Also the push notifications won't be affected?

Comment: @Tarek Hallak, if distribution certificate expires and the app is on live on app store, will receive a push notification or not? Please answer?

Comment: Only if APNS certificate expired, it wont work, otherwise you can send/receive notification, plus you can renew the APNS certificate without updating your app on AppStore.