# What happens when Apple revokes a certificate?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, certificate

Regarding the fact that in iOS distribution model, each App should be signed by a certificate issued by Apple (either developer license, enterprise license, appstore, etc.), I wonder what happens when this certificate gets voided (e.g. because of legal issues) by Apple?

- Does the signed app stop working as soon as the certificate is
  voided?
- Does the signed Apps stop working as soon as the user connects to internet?
- Does the signed Apps continue working, but cannot be updated?
- Does ... ???

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681862/what-happens-if-my-distribution-certificate-expires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signed app remains signed and continues to work. But you will not be able to use the certificate to sign new apps.

Comment: I've downloaded the certificate from apple and have imported it into my xCode. How apple can forbid me from signing new apps?

Comment: Part of the signing process involves Xcode checking with Apple that the certificate is still valid. Among other checks such as checking that the time of your computer is accurate compared to their time server. That's why you'll sometimes see code signing fail, when their time server goes down.

Comment: But I am building and signing my app usually without any connection to the internet on my Mac !!!