# Should I upload new version of iPhone app if certificate expired?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store

I have one  game uploaded on app store and the certificate is expired, what should I do? generate new certificate and upload new version of game to store

Comment: What certificate? Normally you don't have to upload anything if you don't update.

Comment: Duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18682063/757503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is already in production on the App Store, **you don't have to update it**. It will never "expire".

If your APNS (for Push notifications) certificate expired, you have to renew it and use the new one server side. You don't have to update your app.