# Distribution certificate expired ios

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

When i login into apple developer account my distribution certificates are expired. Whether it affect my live apps. Whether i need to give immediate updates to AppStore using new certificates.Please give some suggestions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681862/what-happens-if-my-distribution-certificate-expires

Comment: Live app did'nt affect it right?But push notification is not received.