# Cannot get new Ad Hoc profile to work

Tags: xcode, provisioning

I have read the docs and tried follwoing the excellent instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053710/cannot-renew-an-ad-hoc-profile-before-it-expires-because-no-certificate-matches) but I still cannot build an archive with the new profile.

I set my provisioning Profile for Ad Hoc Distribution to the new profile, then when I archive I get the following and the setting changes to None.

> Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“MyAddHocProfile”) has an AppID of “com.bdh.*” which does not match your bundle identifier “BDH.OrthoPro”.
>   CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'

How do I get my bundle identifier to match the apple ID of the profile.

My bundle ID looks like theis, which I cannot change to match the provisioning profile ID...

[image]

The onley choices I have for an app id on the profile looks like this...

[image]

Thanks for any help...

Comment: "My bundle ID looks like this, which I cannot change" Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message and your screen shots are perfectly clear. `BDH` (the start of your app's bundle id) is very different from `com.bdh` (the start of the app bundle id attached to your OrthoPro profile).

Either change the bundle id in your app target's Info.plist, or register the correct app id with Apple and make a new profile.

Comment: Yes you are right that the error message is perfectly clear. Thanks. I am not having any luck resolving the issue. I also wonder what caused thhis to happen. All was working fine until my ad hoc profile expired and I created a new one. In any event I figured out how to change the bundle ID, but the profile App ID is com.bdh.* If I change the bundle ID to com.bdh.* the build fails with a invalid bundle identifier 'com.bdh.*'

Comment: Since the app id is not available when creating the profile, I am guesisng that my app is no longer registered. I think I have to figure out how to reregister the app. Changing the bundle ID is a problem as the asterisk in com.bdh.* cannot be entered in the plist and without it they will not match. Any help getting the app registered would be appreciated

Comment: The asterisk is a wild card. Use `com.bdh.orthopop` or whatever for the app bundle id. You can add the app at Apple's site manually.

Comment: I have it fixed now. The only solution was to delete the existing registration for the app on the Deve center and recreate it. I am good to go now.