# Push notification Expire duration in case of Adhoc build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

I have created an app, which will be not live in appstore, its just for internal company distribution purpose.

I have 50 employee's having iPhone, but as per company policy they want to create it for internal purpose not want to distribute it.

The app contain push notification.

My query is what is the duration of push notification expire in case i will distribute adhoc build and use distribute APN certificates in my server? Will it work?

I know that for developer mode the Push notification certificates work in 3 month only with one device only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **one year**, for distribution builds, same for Adhoc builds or App Store Distribution builds!!

Comment: will it work for distribution adhoc build ? not live in appstore purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Its expiry time is one year same as Appstore distribution.

Hope these links give some help too.

[Cannot renew an Ad Hoc profile before it expires because no certificate matches the certificate ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053710/cannot-renew-an-ad-hoc-profile-before-it-expires-because-no-certificate-matches)

http://www.duskbeforethedawn.net/2014/06/what-time-does-an-apple-provisioning-profile-expire/

Thanks