# The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

Tags: ios, testing, certificate, device

I want to test my app in a device and I'm stuck with this error for hours:

> The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

I've followed [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html), and I've searched similar questions here on stackoverflow.

This might help: in my Provisioning Profiles my certificates have "Valid signing identity not found" and my Archives tab is empty.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Here is the precise answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449885/how-i-solved-this-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is about what is in your keychain. *Look* in your keychain (with Keychain Access). Do you or do you not have a valid up-to-date development certificate? Hint: it looks like this:

[image]

Except that the one in the screen shot is expired! You need to have one, and it needs to be *not* expired. If you don't have one, then get one.

Comment: i have two certificates: iPhone Developer and iPhone Distribution

Comment: Then I suggest you delete them, and delete all your provisioning profiles, and start over, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13426659/341994

Comment: The other very important part that you didn't mention is **do you have a key with that certificate**?  If yes, it will look like the top left of the image attached to this post (with the expanded triangle).  If no, then the certificate will appear in the keychain on its own and be useless.  In that case you will either have to A) Find the developer who has the key or B) Remake the certificate and for god's sake **SAVE THE KEY SOMEWHERE** so that you can give it to the devs whose signing process you broke, and any new devs that join your team.

Comment: my certificate is like the one in the image attached

Comment: i think it might have something to do with the archives tab in the organizer being completely empty