# IOS developer certificate has expired before expire date

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

Currently, I can not use my devices in `Xcode`. When I checked my keychain, i saw that this certificate has expired, and I can't download it from member center but my certificate expire date is about next month. Is it a usual thing? Did anyone have such situation before? I renewed my developer certificate and waiting for activation e-mail from Apple for two days. I could not find enough information about it.

Thanks

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma  Actually it started two days ago , thanks

Comment: Are you saying you renewed your **certificate** or your **account**? I don't remember ever needing an email when my cert is renewed but renewing your account is a different story. Also, if keychain access is showing it has expired where do you see that it has NOT expired?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's Developer Certificated and Provisioning Profiles. It's better to ask this kind of questions in developer.apple.com


Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to renew your developer certificate. The [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177143/how-to-renew-an-iphone-development-certificate) will be able to guide you through the process.

Comment: thanks for reply. I renewed it two days ago and i still didn't get any activation email or anything like that from Apple.It takes long time? do you have an idea?

Comment: @runmad: the developer portal is currently down (OP didn't mention that).

Answer (score 0):

Apple take its own time to renew your Apple developer a/c and probably its two days as it verifies your payment etc first. At present the Apple developer site is down and up for maintenance. May be this is the reason why you are not able to get any info about it.

Regards

Rajeev