# iOS Distribution Certificate revoked itself in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, certificate

My iOS Distribution Certificate revoked itself in Xcode. Why does this happen and how can i restore it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter *why* it happened. You might have gone onto the Member Center and revoked it. Your membership might have expired. Lots of things *could* have happened to cause it.

In any case, you cannot "restore" it; it is revoked (there is no such thing as "unrevoke"). Simply generate a new distribution certificate.

Comment: The thing is that my Distribution Certificate in Keychain Access still shows as valid. What should i do now?

Comment: I don't understand why the Xcode one is revoked but the Keychain Access one still shows as valid? If i create a new one, will it mess up the old one?

Comment: We're just going around in circles. If I say the same thing again it will be the third time. I don't see the point of that. I'm sorry you don't find my answer useful. Feel free not to make a new one. (Personally, I would quit Xcode and delete the old one, both in the keychain and at the Member Center, before making the new one.)

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make a new one

Comment: This q/a might also prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177143/how-to-renew-an-iphone-development-certificate