# swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem with XCode since 2 days.
I upgraded my iOS Developer Account, and now I can't build on my iphone.
I have this when I try to build.

```
/Users/RpX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moukat-amxiyucfcmxblndkiauwhwnscwhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Moukat.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
*** error: Couldn't codesign /Users/RpX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moukat-amxiyucfcmxblndkiauwhwnscwhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Moukat.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1
```

I tried all solutions on Stackoverflow about certificats, build settings, etc ..., it doesn't work.
If someone know something about it =).
Thank you.

Comment: You should add your code snippet.

Comment: It doesn't work with any project in swift. I have the same error for a new project

Comment: "I upgraded my iOS Developer Account" What does that mean? (I'm trying to understand what change you might have made.)

Comment: My iOS Developer Membership had expired, so I renewed it

Comment: "My iOS Developer Membership had expired, so I renewed it" The answer I link to in my comment below described what I had to do when my membership expired.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to delete everything related to development and distribution certification - all relevant certificates in the keychain, all mobile provisions on disk, and everything at the Member Center - and start the entire process of generating new identities and profiles from scratch.

Comment: See, for example, my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13426659/341994 It isn't as bad as it sounds; I find I have to do this from time to time anyway.

Comment: I already did a lot of time :/ but I'm going to try it again :)

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't think that the problem is my certificates, because a project in Objective-C works with a device.

Comment: But that is just what happened to me about six months ago, and the new certificates and profiles fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded also my iOS Developer Account, and I got the same error in all my Apps when I tried to run them on my Ipad (IOS 11)
This works for me ( I did the samme in all the programs)

1. choose TARGET
2. General/Signing : Automatically manage signing
3. General/Deployment info/Deployment target: change to a lower IOS (I chose 10.0)
4. General/Deployment info/Deployment info/Devices : Universal
5. Build cmd B and  Run cmd R with destination (your device)
6. After the error is disappeared: change the Deployment target to IOS 11 and the Device to iPhone/iPad