# Completely Remove Developer Certificate from Xcode

Tags: xcode, code-signing-certificate

I created a developer certificate in Xcode by going to Preferences -> Accounts -> selecting my Apple ID (connected to my Apple developer account) -> Manage Certificates -> here the list was empty so I clicked the + and selected Apple Development. This created a certificate called MyMac (the name of the Mac machine) with creator being my Apple ID email address.

This certificate does **not** appear in my developer account, so I decided to delete it but instead of deleting it from Xcode, I deleted it from Keychain.

Now when I go to the signing certificates window (same steps as above), I still see the certificate but it is grayed out and the status says "Not in Keychain". The problem is I cannot delete it here in Xcode now (right click shows disabled Delete Certificate option). I cannot create a new development certificate either as it says I already have one.

I found some people saying I should revoke the certificate from my developer account but as mentioned it does not appear there.

How can I remove the certificate from the signing certificates?

Answer (score 0):

You have already deleted your copy of the certificate. If your goal is to delete Apple's copy, go to the portal at `developer.apple.com` and delete it from "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" by clicking the Revoke button.

You cannot remove the certificate from any profiles you may have made using it.

Comment: As I wrote, the certificate is not in the developer account under developer.apple.com, so I cannot revoke it there. I want to remove it completely from my machine but it is still there, just grayed out and no delete command. I have not made any profiles, just the steps described above.

Comment: Why do you want to delete it anyway?

Comment: So that I can create a new one. The current one is gone (I deleted it from the Keychain) and now I just want to start over.

Comment: No but I mean is, what was wrong with the first one? An Apple development certificate is an Apple development certificate.

Comment: It was not inside the developer program on developer.apple.com (no idea why), so I wanted to create it again.

Comment: So you're saying it never appeared at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - it never appear there. But it is somewhere because I even removed my apple ID from the machine and added it again and it reappeared - grayed out as before.

Comment: Did you run any apps with it? It's probably embedded in some of your mobile provisioning profiles. See my https://stackoverflow.com/a/13426659/341994

Comment: I already answered that: nothing done, no apps, no profile - just the steps above: created, seen it was not in the portal, deleted but deleted from inside Keychain instead of inside Xcode.

Comment: I'm with you, but humor me and see the linked suggestion anyway. It tells you to completely clean out your Xcode's knowledge so that nothing remains and you won't see that grayed out identity.